# How to keep track of daily expenses having two currencies?

Tags: currency, budget, expense-tracking, tracking

I want to keep track of my daily expenses using a system as simple as possible. My current choice is to have a spreadsheet where I keep track of my budget:

- One page controls the monthly budget listing all sources of income, outcome and monthly expenses.
- Another page is where I note down every daily expense and its category (which is aggregated to the monthly budget page)

Its structure looks something like this:

- monthly budget:

  - income (salary,interests, other)
  - payments

    - debts (credit cards, rent, others)
    - expenses (variable):

      - housing,
      - transportation,
      - food,
      - health,
      - clothing,
      - others

Each expenses category is filled automatically from another page containing a list of expenses by day with their proper category.

The problem is how to track those expenses when they can be in one of two currencies, to have an accurate budget. The only solution I see is to track them in one currency and convert each other at its daily exchange rate, but that would be very time consuming, is there any other approach? (solution can include using some other software like gnucash)

Comment: Track in one, have another column that shows them multiplied by the value of a cell containing the current exchange rate (so a single change updates that whole column)? Or do you want every value scaled to the exchange rate on that day?

Comment: @keshlam every value scaled to the exchange rate on that day is the only solution I can figure out now, have a single exchange rate would be very inaccurate, I would like to know if there are other alternatives.